# The Filename of the image I'm uploading is not changing

Tags: php, session, mysqli, static

Evertime I upload a picture, the FILENAME is NOT CHANGING the static value(filename) that is inserting in database is always "0.png" I don't know how is that happening, Please Help me how to fix this problem.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("../db_connection.php");

$seller_id = $_SESSION['seller_id'];
$trade_name = $_POST ['trade_name'];
$s_address = $_POST ['s_address'];
$opening_time = $_POST ['opening_time'];
$opening_days = $_POST ['opening_days'];
$order_cutoff = $_POST ['order_cutoff'];
$seller_delivery_time = $_POST ['seller_delivery_time'];
$area_covered_delivery = $_POST ['area_covered_delivery'];
$delivery_fee = $_POST ['delivery_fee'];

 $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['s_image']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$sql = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE selling_details
                   SET
                   opening_time = '$opening_time',
                   opening_days = '$opening_days',
                   order_cutoff = '$order_cutoff',
                   seller_delivery_time = '$seller_delivery_time',
                   area_covered_delivery = '$area_covered_delivery',
                   delivery_fee = '$delivery_fee'
                   WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
            if ($sql)
    {
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
        $filename = $id.'.'.$extension;

        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['s_image']['tmp_name'], 'upload/'.$filename))
    {
        $sql2 = mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE seller
               SET
               trade_name = '".$trade_name."',
               s_address = '".$s_address."',
               s_image = '".$filename."' 
               WHERE seller_id= '" . $_SESSION['seller_id'] . "' ");
        if ($sql2)
        {

            header('location: seller_menu.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "error occured : " . mysqli_error($db);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error occured : " . mysqli_error($db);
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You're using mysqli_insert_id($db); on an `UPDATE` query. this will not work and will always return 0.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Check out [this page](http://bobby-tables.com/) for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`mysqli_insert_id`](http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id) returns the id of the row you just inserted into your database, and since you don't insert anything (you just update) the value the function returns is 0, so the name of your image is `$id.'.'.$extension` ==> `0.png`.

Since you update the `seller_id`, and you have it inside `$_SESSION['seller_id']`, you can use it in your code:

```
    $filename = $_SESSION['seller_id'].'.'.$extension;
```